# Writing lat long co-ordinates for an 2-d array and making a .nc file out of it

Tags: arrays, python-xarray, netcdf

I started with a binary file that had elevation data and following details:

### GENEARAL INFORMATION ABOOUT THE DATASETS

```
nx=42600   
ny=39600  
resolution=0.000833   
lonmin=64.500000000  
lonmax=100.000000000    
latmin=5.000000000   
latmax=38.000000000
```

I read the binary file into an array and reshaped it using (nx, ny) as follows::

```
type here
```

data_array = data_array.reshape((ny, nx))

Now since this array values correspond to an elevation of a sutiable grid size that I have mentioned above, I tried creating a lat and lon named array and finally making a .nc file in this manner.

```
lon = np.linspace(lonmin, lonmax, nx)
lat = np.linspace(latmin, latmax, ny)
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "data": (["lat", "lon"], data_array),
    },
    coords={"lon": lon, "lat": lat}
)
ds.to_netcdf("merit_elevtn.nc")
```

When I try to plot my data from this file, created
I get the following plot::

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyst5.png)

As you can see rather than the lat and lon nx and ny are in the plot. Am I doing something wrong here ?

Please let me know if is there any error in my way of assigning latitude and longitude co-ordinates to this array or is there any better way to do this.
Also  I downloaded this file and tried to work it out with QGIS but found that the file is being plotted in this way
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OGuu.png)

Also If I am trying now to clip the file for specifc latitude and longitudes, the clipped file does not match the required topography.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is important that things are reproducible by others. For example, you show us a plot, but not how it was created. Or how you created the dataset. So you are just leaving people guessing what the problem is.